# how guice just in time binding works in play framework?

Tags: java, scala, dependency-injection, playframework, guice

How do I inject the dependencies I have created in Play application. I also do not understand looking at the examples how they are injected without defining any binding.

https://github.com/manuelbernhardt/reactive-web-applications/blob/master/CH04/app/controllers/Quiz.scala

Can anyone explain with reference to this example. How is object of VocabularyService injected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is more about dependency injection than it is about the Play Framework.

The reason that you don't have to define an explicit binding for the `VocabularyService` is that Guice can find it for you:

> When a dependency is requested but not found it attempts to create a just-in-time binding.

from: [Guice Bindings](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Bindings)

On the [documentation of just-in-time bindings](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/JustInTimeBindings) you can see that the option for creating a just-in-time binding are `Eligible Constructors`, `@ImplementedBy` and `@ProvidedBy`.

In our case, the class `VocabularyService` has a default non-private, no-arguments constructor.